# Couldn’t acquire exclusive lock on DB at ‘/eventstore/db’

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, eventstoredb

I’m trying to install eventstore on ubuntu 20.04 but everytime I run `evenstored --what-if` (as root or as simple user, or as sudo) I get the following error message : `Couldn't acquire exclusive lock on DB at '/eventstore/db'.`.

I tried many things :

- I tried ensuring that eventstore user and group were owner of the folder.
- reinstalling eventstore
- rebooting server
- stop process with `systemctl stop eventstore` and starting it back again
  I also tried launching service first (as root / sudo or simple user) before using `eventstored --what-if`.

I can’t figure out why I keep getting this message as if many instance of eventstore where launched at the same time.

---

EDIT :

Here is my config file (`/etc/eventstore/eventstore.conf`)

```
# Paths
Db: /eventstore/db
Index: /eventstore/index
Log: /eventstore/logs

# Certificates configuration
CertificateFile: /etc/eventstore/certs/cert.crt
CertificatePrivateKeyFile: /etc/eventstore/certs/privkey.key
TrustedRootCertificatesPath: /etc/ssl/certs
CertificateReservedNodeCommonName: "*.mathob-jehanno.com"
# Network configuration
IntIp: 37.187.2.103
ExtIp: 37.187.2.103
IntHostAdvertiseAs: mathob-jehanno.com
ExtHostAdvertiseAs: mathob-jehanno.com
HttpPort: 2113
IntTcpPort: 1112
EnableExternalTcp: false
EnableAtomPubOverHTTP: false

# Projections configuration
RunProjections: None
```

Comment: did you try sudo lsof | grep /eventstore/db ? you might need to apt-get install lsof first

Comment: How am I suppose to use the result, lsof returned a huge list I don't know what is "normal" and what is not :o

Comment: If lsof returns a huge list, it means that the process listed in columns 1 <name> and 2 <pid> are using the /eventstore/db, hence the "Couldn't acquire exclusive lock" message. You may kill the process(es) with kill <pid> .

Comment: hm I tried to kill the process but it keep restarting, moreover with the name of the process for me it looks like it's just some eventstore related process

Comment: I stopped the eventstore service, tried lsof, it returned nothing. I restarted eventstore service, I had the exact same huge list

Comment: are you seeing anything in the logs before that message? specifically something around the "previous instance was terminated abruptly" ?

Comment: I have a "Invalid Configuration Encountered" ... didn't saw that, yet it doesn't say what is wrong, I'll check ! thanks

Comment: I tried running in insecure mod  to see if it was a problem from certificates yet the problem still appear

Comment: as the service keeps restarting, it is probably spawned by systemd. try "systemctl -a | grep eventstore". In the first column, you will get a xxx.service . To stop it: systemctl stop xxx.service. To prevent start at next boot: systemctl disable xxx.service

Comment: That will not solve the problem as, eventstore is telling that it's a configuration problem. I can edit my post and add my config if you want

Comment: the config would help. also make sure that all paths in the config exist and are available (security/space etc) there are out of space errors that can manifest as that error unfortunately.

Comment: I edited my question to add my configuration. I checked all the path in this file and all exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so

First of all, comments helped a lot :

this error message is following another one which give more detail about what the problem is.

One thing to know is that `eventstored --what-if` is supposed to be run while service is not running so user need to stop the service before (`systemctl stop eventstore`).

I then changed the path to db, index and logs file to match the default value (it prevented me some permissions error).

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me previously. I was running v20 without supplying the necessary settings like the certificates were missing. The server crashed because of this, but the last message you see is this `Couldn't acquire exclusive lock on DB at '/eventstore/db'`. You might look close and see if it's a *warning*, and the real reason for the crash is mentioned earlier in the stack trace of the original error.